# shrinking text in UILabel

Tags: iphone

i hv a label of width 100 px,but dynamically i am filling that label.
so the text's length is not fixed, so it can be anything, 10 or 30.
the problem i am facing is, when the text length exceeds, the font size of  the text in UIlabel gets smaller and complete text comes up in uilabel.

i was trying if, the text length gets exceeds, it should show something like this 
"abcdefghijklm"   to   "abc...."

with the same font size...something like adjust size to fit .
how can do dat?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set label property

```
yourLabelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property for the same size of frame for your label. but if you need to show the label contents in the same font size then you can use this thing:

labelname.numberofLine=0;

And you can change the font hight accordingly so that your label contents will set in proper format with the required font size.